# Check for edit mode excel from access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I run into several issues in my Access application when Excel is in edit mode at the same time.

How can I check if an Excel application is in edit mode from Access (VBA Code)?  (So I can stop the Access makro and tell the users to close Excel before they continue)

Thank you very much smart people!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the excel application is still open in your VBA code, then try these methods.
Firstly, check if all the referenced objects, recordsets, are closed in VBA code. Also the objects  and recordsets must be set to nothing.

Or Check your task Manager, there might be an instance of Excel application open.

If not these, what do you really want to do? because when you write a code to fetch data from excel it prompts the user to close the Excel application automatically.